# Inconsistent fonts when viewing edit diff

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, ios-app

I just [edited a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41490778/23649) in the iOS app to remove extraneous indentation. I then viewed the diff to make sure the edit did what I intended, and I saw this:

[image: screenshot]

Looks like it starts out as Menlo/Monaco, and switches to Courier partway through?

- App Version: 1.6.2.5
- Device: iPhone 7
- OS Version: Version 10.2 (Build 14C92)

Comment: Oy, there are so many problems with that diff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.6.3.3.

Ignoring the fact that the diff is a train wreck, the problem is that somehow the code between the changes is not in a `<code>` tag and we only defined a font for `code` and not `pre`.

Added a font rule for `pre`.

Comment: Thanks! Is the diff computed on the server or in the app?

Comment: @jtbandes In the app, there's probably an implementation bug or it could be related to some properties I've changed for performance reasons. (Swift 2 strings were terribly slow in debug builds.)